# How to build docker image with Dockerfile from Asp.NetCore Project

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have the following project structure:

[image]

The automatically generated Dockerfile contains the following code:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Account/Portal.Account.API/Portal.Account.API.csproj", "Account/Portal.Account.API/"]
COPY ["Common/Portal.Common.Persistence/Portal.Common.Persistence.csproj", "Common/Portal.Common.Persistence/"]
COPY ["Common/Portal.Common.Domain/Portal.Common.Domain.csproj", "Common/Portal.Common.Domain/"]
COPY ["Common/Portal.Common.Service/Portal.Common.Service.csproj", "Common/Portal.Common.Service/"]
COPY ["Account/Portal.Account.Domain/Portal.Account.Domain.csproj", "Account/Portal.Account.Domain/"]
COPY ["Account/Portal.Account.Persistence/Portal.Account.Persistence.csproj", "Account/Portal.Account.Persistence/"]
COPY ["Account/Portal.Account.Service/Portal.Account.Service.csproj", "Account/Portal.Account.Service/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Account/Portal.Account.API/Portal.Account.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Account/Portal.Account.API"
RUN dotnet build "Portal.Account.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Portal.Account.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Portal.Account.API.dll"]
```

But when I try to build the image I get the error that the one or more project files is not found

[image]

How can I resolve this and build the docker image successfully.

Comment: You know what's funny? You've managed to white-out the single most important piece of information in your post - the `docker build` command.

Comment: @HansKilian The docker build command I used is as follows:

 docker build -t myUserName/my-repo-name:the-tag-name .

Comment: Use `..` at the end instead of `.`

Comment: @HansKilian I get this error when I use .. 
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3823444894/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: Ah, OK. Try `docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t myUserName/my-repo-name:the-tag-name ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to find out that I need to put the Dockerfile outside the parent directory where the project I was trying to build is. So I had to put the Dockerfile outside the "Account" directory before it could run. It has to be in the directory housing the Account directory. That means I could not build the docker image while the Dockerfile was inside the directory where the project it located.

This could be probably because it needs to copy other referenced projects that are adjacent/outside the project where it is located.

So it has to sit side by side the .sln file before I could build the image successfully.

I hope this saves someone else some troubleshooting time

[image]

Comment: What command did you type to build the Docker image? I need to do the same thing.